# How to fix this "divide by zero" error in percentage calculation?

Tags: php

I have this error message:

```
Division by zero (View: /var/www/Hotbit/resources/views/admin/user_stats.blade.php) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Division by zero (View: /var/www/Hotbit/resources/views/admin/user_stats.blade.php) at /var/www/Hotbit/resources/views/admin/user_stats.blade.php:49)
```

Code:

```
100 - (\DB::table('users')
           ->where('email', '!=', null)
           ->where('chat_role', '<=', 3)
           ->count() /
       \DB::table('users')
           ->where('email', null)
           ->where('chat_role', '<=', 3)
           ->count()
      )*100
```

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that `->count()` is returning `0`

Comment: Store the results of the queries to variables, then check for bad conditions, like a zero denominator.

Comment: supposing ->where('email', null) is searching how many null e-mails  and the all system give permissions to access only registered then is a dev error 'cause you always have 0 email null since all are users registered by an e-mail  (in case the email suppose to mean that)

Answer (score -1):

In maths a number divided by zero is undefined. If you get a divide by zero error then you asked a computer to do something impossible.

As Chris Haas has guessed - I too expect that `->count()` is returning a zero. You will need some way to spot a zero and return one or something.